# Delete registry key from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE when logged on as a standard user

Tags: windows-7

I want to delete a registry key from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE on a Windows 7 PC when a standard user is logged on, what would be the best way of doing this?

The command below works when logged on as administrator.

Reg DELETE HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test\ /f

Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-privileged users cannot normally do that, unless you have edited the permissions on the registry key to allow for this.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Admin credentials, go to c:\windows\ and right-click regedit.exe and choose Run As Administrator. then you should be able to do what you want. If not, see previous two answers.